# What is the class of all complex, Lebesgue measurable, 2$\pi$-periodic function?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, periodic-functions

In Rudin's RCA, there is a section about trigonometric series.

Here, he defines $L^p(T)$, for $1 \le p < \infty$, to be the class of all complex, Lebesgue measurable, **2$\pi$-periodic functions** on $\mathbb{R}$ for which the norm

$\Vert f \Vert_p = \Big \{ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \vert f(t) \vert^p \,dt \Big\}^{1/p} $

My question is focused on the **periodic** part. As far as I know, $L^p$ space is technically equivalence classes. So, even a function defined on $[0,2\pi]$ with $f(0) \neq f(2\pi)$ can be replaced with another function $g$ which is the same as $f$ with $g(0) = g(2\pi)$ and then it can be expanded over $\mathbb{R}$.

Or, should I understand the periodic $L^p$ function $f$ to be periodic a.e.?

Or, can say $f$ is periodic in $L^p$ if there is another function $g$ such that $f=g$ a.e. and $g$ is periodic as a function?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there is any salient difference between your two possible interpretations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So, even though $f$ is not periodic as a function, we can say $f$ is periodic in $L^p$ if there is another function $g$ such that $f = g$ a.e. and $g$ is periodic as a function?

Comment: As far as $L^p$ is concerned, these distinctions barely matter....

Comment: Once it is clarified, it will not matter, I guess. However, for now, I am a little confused, so that's why I am asking.

Comment: The latter definition you suggest is how I would think it. It gives the same set of functions that Rudin had in mind, and if it doesn't, it's Rudin's fault for not making it explicit.

Comment: @user3010768 Thanks for your comment! So, by latter one, you mean this one? "$f$ is periodic in $L^p$ if there is another function $g$ such that $f=g$ a.e. and $g$ is periodic as a function."

Comment: Yes, that indeed. :)

Comment: @user3010768 Thank you very much for your confirmation! Really helpful! :)